# How do I create new arrays from a parent array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
```

I want to extract the array values and transfer each one to its own array variable. The result would look like this:

```
arr1=[1]
arr2=[2]
arr3=[3]
```

I have tried using the following code, but am not getting the desired result.

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3];
var myarr1=[];
var myarr2=[];
var myarr3=[];
var result = myArray.map(function(current){ 
    return myarr1.push(current);                     
});                                        

console.log(myarr1)
```

How can I move each value to its own variable?

Comment: `var myarr1 = [myArray[0]]` etc... What is your reason for doing this though? Seems like a 2d array might be better for this?

Comment: Creating entirely separate variables seems a needlessly restrictive step when a 2d array would work better: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6j4o2pgz/

Comment: In which scenario this  is needed??

Comment: just do `arrayOfArrays = array.map(x => [x])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
var myarr1=[];
var myarr2=[];
var myarr3=[];
var result = [myarr1, myarr2, myarr3];
function fillInArrays(element, index) {
  result[index].push(element);
}
myArray.forEach(fillInArrays);                                        

console.log(myarr1, myarr2, myarr3)
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you put those arrays in an object, use reduce to loop through the array and assign the values :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const arrays = arr.reduce((acc, curr, ndx) => {
  acc['myArr' + (ndx+1)] = [curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(arrays);
```

But if you ( not recommended ) really really need global variables, use the put them in the `window` object :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.forEach((element, ndx) => {
  window['myArr' + (ndx + 1)] = [element];
});

console.log(myArr1);
console.log(myArr2);
console.log(myArr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3];

var dynamicArr = new Array(myArray.length);

for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
  var Arr = []; Arr.push(myArray[x]);
  dynamicArr[x] = Arr;
}

console.log(dynamicArr)
```